# Inverse of Natural Projection?

Tags: homological-algebra

May this be a silly question, but can I construct an inverse of a natural projection $p$ from a module $M$ to its quotient module $M/A$? Of course more than one element can be assigned for each coset in $M/A$, but if we limit the inverse's range to direct complement of $A$, I think such inverse could be well-defined.

As far as I know such inverse homomorphism might be useful for various situations but I have never seen any.

There were only isomorphisms from the quotient module $M/A$ itself. There might be some reason for this. Can anyone teach me? Thank you!

Comment: Such an “inverse” (in general only a left inverse) exists precisely when $A$ is a direct summand of $M$.

Comment: Now then how can I depict such inverse? Just $$p^-1$$ will not work.

Comment: The (two-sided) inverse exists if and only if the canonical projection is an isomorphism, which means $A=\{0\}$; not a very interesting case, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an exact sequence
$$ 0 \longrightarrow A \overset{i}\longrightarrow M \overset{p}\longrightarrow M/A \longrightarrow 0.$$
By the [Splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma), this sequence splits, i.e. $M\cong A\oplus M/A$, exactly if there is a morphism $r:M/A\to M$ such that $p\circ r = \operatorname{id}_{M/A}$. Look at the proof of the splitting lemma to see how to construct $r$ from the isomorphism $M\overset{\sim}\rightarrow A\oplus M/A$ and how to construct this isomorphism from a given right-inverse $r$ of $p$.

Comment: Thank you! Learning algebra without mathematical maturity is queit confusing... :)

Comment: Homological algebra is a beautiful theory, I wish you the best on your journey!

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the language of exact sequences?  [The Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_sequence) is a good introduction.  Given a module $M$ with submodule $A$, there is a natural short exact sequence $0 \to A \to M \to M/A \to 0$.  The first (non-zero) arrow is the inclusion $i$ and the second (non-zero) arrow is the projection $p$.

You are asking if there is a homomorphism $s: M/A \to M$ with the property that $(p \circ s) = id_{M/A}$.  Such a map is not guaranteed to exist.  For a simple example, consider the short exact sequence of abelian groups ($\mathbb{Z}$-modules) $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to 0$$ where the first map is multiplication by $m$.   The only homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the zero map, so there's no "inverse" to the projection.

The [splitting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma) from homological algebra says that such a map exists if and only if
$M$ is the direct sum of $M/A$ and $A$.  If you want an example with a more natural inclusion, consider $\mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q}$.  Note that $\mathbb{Q} \neq \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you! Actually my focus was the situations where A is a direct summand of M. So learning about the splitting lemma might help me a lot.